Python + Selenium で onclick="change(this) を操作したいのですが、例外が発生します。
東京ディズニーランドのレストランの自動予約プログラムを作成しています。
開発環境
MacBook Air / macOS Big Sur
Python 3.12.1
Selenium 4.19.0
予約の条件設定ページ
https://reserve.tokyodisneyresort.jp/restaurant/search/
を表示して「時間帯」で、例えば「夕食」のチェックボックスをクリックするコードを実装したいと考えています。
予約の条件設定ページの該当するソースは次のようになっています。
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checobox4" class="checkbox" value="3" name="mealDivList[2]" onclick="change(this);" autocomplete="off">
  <label for="checobox4" class="checkboxLabel">夕食</label>
</li>

そこで次のようにテストコードを実装しました。
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# TDL対策
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# 予約トップページ
restaurant_URL = 'https://reserve.tokyodisneyresort.jp/restaurant/search/'

# 予約トップページの表示
driver.get(restaurant_URL)
sleep(5)

# 同意ウィンドウのボタンをクリックする。
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a:has(img[alt="閉じる"])').click()
sleep(1)

# 予約する食事の時間帯を選ぶ。
driver.find_element(By.ID,'checobox4').click()

sleep(30)
driver.quit()

しかしコンソールから実行したところ、次の例外メッセージが発生しました。
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Development/scraping/Disney/disney_res.py", line 47, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.ID,cource_id).click()
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 94, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/admin/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="checkbox" id="checobox4" class="checkbox" value="3" name="mealDivList[2]" onclick="change(this);" autocomplete="off"> is not clickable at point (708, 264). Other element would receive the click: <label for="checobox4" class="checkboxLabel">...</label>
  (Session info: chrome=126.0.6478.127)
Stacktrace:
(省略)

onclick="change(this);" を実行するようにしないといけないのか、不明です。
問題を解決できる方、ご教示をお願いいたします。
なお、ソースでは動作に関係ないところを省くために 'checobox4' とリテラルになっていますが、実際には変数 cource_id を使って文字列 'checobox4' を渡しています。

エラーメッセージで検索するとdriver.execute_script()に変えた方が良いらしいですね。【Selenium】（Python）ハマった時のメモ, Not able to click on checkbox using selenium in Python,Error- selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException, ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted Element is not clickable error clicking a radio button using Selenium and Python, "Element click intercepted" Error...
